# How to make Python function return static variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to build a [WTForms custom validator](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators) to check for duplicate image hashes. To do this I'm using a nested function in my form validator. The problem is when I set a variable (result of inner function) in the outer function, any subsequent references to the outer variable  call the inner function again.

For example:

```
def dupe_check(self, field):
    def get_hash():
        f = field.data
        img = Image.open(f)
        imghash = imagehash.dhash(img)
        f.seek(0)
        return imghash
    imghash = get_hash()
    hashcheck = Sights.query.filter(Sights.image_hash == imghash).first()
    if hashcheck == imghash:
        print('dupe')
        raise ValidationError('duplicate hash!')
    else:
        print('no dupe')
```

If run with no hash in database, I print `no dupe` and the image is uploaded.

However, if the hash exists in the database, when execution reaches `if hashcheck == imghash:` I crash because it appears that `imghash` is calling `get_hash()` again and not simply returning the hash string that was previously set with `imghash = get_hash()`.

You can see below that the `imagehash` program is getting called (and crashes) instead of simply the hash string.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2017 17:49:36] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/project/sights/views.py", line 74, in add_image
    if form.validate_on_submit():
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 204, in validate
    stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 224, in _run_validation_chain
    validator(form, self)
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/project/sights/forms.py", line 71, in dupe_check
    if hashcheck == imghash:
  File "/home/mrrg/dev/flaskimg/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imagehash/__init__.py", line 85, in __eq__
    return numpy.array_equal(self.hash.flatten(), other.hash.flatten())
AttributeError: 'Sights' object has no attribute 'hash'
```

I thought `imghash = get_hash()` will set a new instance of the variable returned from the inner function? How can I set a static variable to operate against, and avoid additional calls to the inner function?

I also tried setting global/nonlocal on the inner function's `imghash` with same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your code tries to compare a Sight object to a ImageHash object, but the Sight class code implementation only compares between 2 Sight object only, so the error appears

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I'm not comparing within a Sight class. I define 2 variables: `imghash` is created from the inner function, and `hashcheck` is created from a SQLAlchemy query.

Comment: Can you show me the type of variable hashcheck and imghash ?

Comment: Ah I see, I have two different variable types: `<class 'imagehash.ImageHash'>` and `<class 'project.models.Sights'>`. What is the best way to normalize the variables for comparison?

Comment: For hash values, I think casting the object type to string for comparison is appropriate

Comment: This ended up working. Thanks for the help @Tung-vs.